# Angular: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to iterate through an Object that I receive through a service call and then placing this iteration onto a table using *ngFor.

However I receive the following error when trying to do so.

```
Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
```

I understand you can't iterate through an Object but when I was trying to look for a solution it didn't quite make sense to me. Please see my code below, any help will be greatly appreciated :

**.ts**

```
searchValue: string = "3";
logList: any = [];
   
getLogs() {
        const numOfLogs = new FormData();
        numOfLogs.append('n_log', this.searchValue)
        this.fileUploadService.getLogs(numOfLogs).subscribe(
          data =>  {this.logList = data},
        );
      }
```

**html**

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="width:1000px;table-layout:fixed;font-size:10px;color:black;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>FilePath</th>
                        <th>Updated</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of logList">
                        <td>{{ item.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.Date}}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.FilePath}}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.Updated}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**console.log(this.logList)**

```
{
  "Name": [
    "name1",
    "name2",
    "name3"
  ],
  "Date": [
    "2021-12-13",
    "2021-12-12",
    "2021-12-11"
  ],
  "FilePath": [
    "FileName1.xlsx",
    "FileName2.xlsx",
    "FileName3.xlsx",
  ],
  "Updated": [
    "2021-12-31T00:00:00",
    "2021-12-31T00:00:00",
    "2021-12-31T00:00:00",
  ],
}
```

Comment: It is quite obvious that `logList` is not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use keyValue pipe since loglist is not a array , below code will solve your problem

```
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td *ngFor="let item of logList | keyvalue"">{{ item.value}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: loop on td instead of tr.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that. Hence why i deleted that comment. However, its seems everything is now in one row. I.e. it comes out {Success,Success,Success} for one column. And the column and values pairs in the table don't match. How would i force that change?

Comment: ok, if it solved your problem accept the answer which will be helpful for others as well.

Comment: Sure. But are able to help to advise on the second issue?

Comment: for that, you should map loglist data to an array of objects in ts file using the Map operator.

Answer (score 1):

`*ngFor` doesn't let you iterate Objects. What should it iterate, the keys of the object, or the values?

I'm guessing that if you ran:

```js
this.fileUploadService.getLogs(numOfLogs).subscribe(
    data =>  { console.log(typeof data); this.logList = data;},
);
```

It would log 'object'.

If you want to iterate an object in the template, you can either convert it to an array/iterable in the .ts file and use that instead:

```
let iterableLogList = Object.keys(this.logList);
```

or you can pipe `this.logList` into Angular's builtin `keyvalue` pipe.

```
*ngFor="let item of logList | keyvalue"
```

you shouldn't need to import anything new to use that. Now, the key of each item will be available in the template as `item.key`, and likewise the value will be available as `item.value`.

Comment: Thank you. I went with the kevalue pipe option.  However, its seems everything is now in one row. I.e. it comes out {Success,Success,Success} for one column. And the column and values pairs in the table don't match. How would i force that change?

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. I figured the error came up (in my case) because the array was empty (I was checking values which would get assigned after an http service call returned). All I needed do was use a conditional clause:

```
            <tbody *ngIf="logList">
                <tr *ngFor="let item of logList">
                ...
```